# How to properly structure angular app with multiple modules that can access one another?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

I am still getting used to Angular and how to properly structure different components and modules. I want to set my app up according to best practices and maximize efficiency. I currently have multiple modules. I have a "base" module that I want to navigate to, but depending on the URL, I want to incorporate components from other modules. Here is how my app-routing.module is currently set up:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BaseComponent },
  { path: 'featureone', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-one/feature-one.module').then(m => m.FeatureOneModule) },
  { path: 'featuretwo', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-two/feature-two.module').then(m => m.FeatureTwoModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

I understand this routing is not set up properly, but I am not sure how I can properly set this up in the most efficient way.

Currently, if I navigate to `''`, it will load the BaseComponent as expected. If I add
`<app-feature-one></app-feature-one>`
or
`<app-feature-two></app-feature-two>`
to the BaseComponent template, it will throw an error like "Cannot access 'FeatureOneModule' before initialization"

Is there some way where I could keep routes such as 'featureone' and 'featuretwo' where it would navigate to the BaseComponent, and I could add logic to display `<app-feature-one></app-feature-one>`
or
`<app-feature-two></app-feature-two>` and only load FeatureOneModule if I navigate to 'featureone' or FeatureTwoModule if I navigate to 'featuretwo'?

Comment: you mean for featureone and featuretwo route, you want to display BaseComponent PLUS featureone or featuretwo components?

Comment: Yes, I want the "base" to show for every route, but depending on the route, there will be a different feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current configuration, because `{ path: '', component: BaseComponent },` is first, no matter what url you issue, it will always resolve to `BaseComponent`. Angular resolves route by performing a DFS search and will **stop at the first match**, so you'd have to be concise when defining the routes.

A way to solve this would be do add `pathMatch: 'full'`:

```js
{ path: '', component: BaseComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
...
```

> it will throw an error like "Cannot access 'FeatureOneModule' before initialization"

You are getting this error because `app-feature-one` and `app-feature-two` are components that belong to lazy-loaded modules, so, unless you *imperatively* import those modules, you won't be able to use them.

> Is there some way where I could keep routes such as 'featureone' and 'featuretwo'  ...

A quick way to solve this would be to use **named outlets**:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', component: BaseComponent, pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
       { path: 'featureone', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-one/feature-one.module').then(m => m.FeatureOneModule), outlet: 'feat-one' },
  { path: 'featuretwo', loadChildren: () => import('./feature-two/feature-two.module').then(m => m.FeatureTwoModule), outlet: 'feat2' },
   ]

  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

then, in your `base-component.component.html`

```html
<router-outlet name="feat-one"></router-outlet>

<!-- ... -->

<router-outlet name="feat-two"></router-outlet>
```

In order to navigate to one of them(or to **both at the same time**), you'll have to use something like this:

```html
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'feat-one': 'featureone' } ... }]"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want your `BaseComponent` to show up for every route, you should include it into your AppComponent component :

```html
<app-base></app-base>
```

If the feature component needs to be displayed as a sibling of base component, just place the router outlet accordingly:

```html
<app-base></app-base>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If the feature component should be nested into some part of your baseComponent, you can use content projection :

```html
<app-base>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-base>
```

Then in your BaseComponent, use `ng-content` :

```html
<header></header>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
<footer></footer>
```